# Shortest distance from a point to vertices of a cube

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

A $d$ dimension cube has vertices $P_1,...,P_{2^d}$, where the coordinates of each vertex are either $0$ or $1$. To find which vertex of $P_1,...P_{2^d}$ is closest to a given point $P=(p_1, ...,p_i,..., p_d)'$, an efficient algorithm can be that for each $p_i$, if $p_i>1/2$, set $x_i=1$, otherwise $x_i=0$. Then the closest vertex is $(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_d)'$. The complexity of this algorithm is $O(d)$.

What if we do a transform of all the points by a linear mapping? What will be an efficient algorithm to find which vertex of $A*P_1,...,A*P_{2^d}$ is closest to the given point $Q=A*(p_1, ...,p_i,..., p_d)'$? Suppose $A$ is positive definite $d$ dimension matrix. The worst complexity is $O(2^d)$, by calculating distance of each vertex to $Q$.

Written in optimization form:

$$min_x \quad || Ax-b||_2$$
$$s.t_ \quad x_i \in\{0,1\}$$
with $A$ being positive definite.

Comment: I think you've written $O(p)$ where you meant $O(d)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes you are right. A typo.

Comment: I don't see how there can be any efficient way to solve this. Where you to solve this, which is equivalent to the binary least-squares you have written down, you would be able to solve minimization of the convex quadratic $\frac{1}{2}x^TQx$  over the binary lattice, a well-known NP-hard problem (just let $b=0$ and $A$ a symmetric psd factorization of $Q$)

Comment: sorry, there should be a linear term also in the quadratic program, otherwise it is trivial, and $b$ has to defined accordingly when rewriting it to your form

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks for your answer. The linear term adds a shift to the paraboloid.